# GNU Arm Embedded C Toolchain Skipping Memory Addresses When Pushing Onto the Stack?

Tags: c, stack, embedded, stm32f4

I was just stepping through some simple C code I'd written for an [STM32F4](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f4-series.html?querycriteria=productId=SS1577) development board.  I'm building the code using the [GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm).  The main function is simple:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int ledOn1 = LED1;  // (1 << 12)
    unsigned int ledOn2 = LED3;  // (1 << 14)

    Init(ledOn1, ledOn2);        //  <-- First breakpoint
    while(1);
}
```

The Init function is simple too:

```
void Init(int led1, int led2)
{
    // Set given LEDs
    lightsOn = led1 | led2;  //  <-- Second breakpoint

    // Etc...
}
```

What's interesting to me is how data is pushed on the stack when the function call is made.

Setting a breakpoint at the line in "main" where the Init function is called, the stack pointer is `0x2001fff0` and the stack looks like this:

[image]

Then the next breakpoint is set at the first line of code in Init() - the line `lightsOn = led1 | led2;`.  So when advancing there we see the stack change as follows:

[image]

We see the old stack pointer of `0x2001FFF0` was pushed onto the stack at memory position `0x2001FFEC`.  And the arguments to the Init function were also pushed onto the stack at positions `0x2001FFE4` and `0x2001FFE0`.  However, I am not sure why memory address `0x2001FFE8` on the stack was skipped?  Anyone?

Comment: Likely the Application Binary Interface requires the stack pointer be 16-byte aligned. (This requirement allows any routine to store objects at 16-byte aligned locations using constant offsets from the stack pointer, without having to test or adjust the stack pointer.)

Comment: In addition to alignment concerns, perhaps the spare bytes are reserved to store the 32 bit return address.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Doesn't appear to be the case.  When passing in three arguments (while keeping the initial SP the same - `0x2001FFF0`) memory address `0x2001FFFE8`is still skipped and the three arguments are placed in `0x2001FFE4`, 0x2001FFE0` and `0x2001FFDC`.

Comment: @Lundin - I thought about that and did a test changing `Init()` to return an unsigned int value but no, the address was still unused - `0x2001FFE8` still contained `0xDEADBEEF` after the function returned.

Comment: What happens if instead of calling `Init` from `main`, you wrap it in another function called from `main`?

Comment: @DKrueger - Thanks for the suggestion.  Just tried, same deal.  Puts the SP into the next location of the stack, skips 4 bytes and then puts the parameters into the next two stack locations.

Comment: Could it be reserved for variables, named or temporary, local to Init()?

Comment: @AlphaBetaKilo: try toggling the compiler optimizations...

Comment: What is the address of lightsOn ? I.e. `&lightsOn`.